# Remove options from a list based on other values in an object?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array of objects that is bound to my html component. I need to remove currencies from the currencies array based on IF the same storeTypeId is chosen that is already in the array, with a particular currency value chosen.

For instance, in the example below Assisted Living is chosen with a currency value of USD, and you can see that Assisted Living is chosen again but you should NOT be able to choose USD again.

Below I have examples of all the TS and HTLML that is involved. In the HTML, where the options are set for the currency, I call a function as such **getStoreTypeCurrencies(item.CurrencyId, item.StoreTypeId)**, and this is where I need assistance. I'm super close, but missing something simple I think...

**See Below For Examples**

[image]

**Type Script Declarations Bound to HTML Component**

```
    currencies: string[];
    storeTypeRateSetting: StoreTypeDetails[] = [new StoreTypeDetails()];

        getStoreTypeCurrencies(currentCurrency: string, currentStoreTypeId: number) {

        if (!currentCurrency || !currentStoreTypeId) return this.currencies;

        var currenciesToCompare = [];
        var availableCurrencies = [];

        this.storeTypeRateSetting.forEach(x => {
          if (x.StoreTypeId == currentStoreTypeId) {
            if (x.CurrencyId) currenciesToCompare.push(x.CurrencyId);
          }
        });

        availableCurrencies = _.difference(this.currencies, currenciesToCompare);

        if (currentCurrency) availableCurrencies.push(currentCurrency);

        return availableCurrencies.sort();
    }
```

**HTML Component**

```html
<!-- default rate for each Store Type -->
<!-- default rate for each Store Type -->
<accordion-group [isOpen]="selectedRateType == 2" heading="A different rate for each Store Type" [panelClass]="customClass" (isOpenChange)="rateTypeChanged(2)">
<div class="form-field" style="padding-top: 10px;">
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="showCurrencyError == true">You must choose a Currency Value</div>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="showStoreTypeError == true">You must set a Store Type</div>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="showStoreTypeRateError == true">You must set a Store Type rate value greater than 0</div>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="showDuplicatesError == true">Duplicate Rate Settings are not permitted, please remove duplicates</div>
  <label class="form-field">Set the default rate for each Store Type</label>
  <div *ngFor="let item of storeTypeRateSetting">
    <div class="col-md-12 d-flex">
      <div class="col-md-1 text-right">
        <i class="bi bi-trash remove-item" (click)="removeStoreType(item)"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <select (change)="validateStoreType(item.StoreTypeId)" class="form-control form-field field-height" [(ngModel)]="item.StoreTypeId" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
          <option></option>
          <option *ngFor="let storeType of storeTypes" [value]="storeType.StoreTypeId">{{storeType.Description}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <input (change)="validateStoreTypeRate(item.value)" type="number" class="form-control form-field field-height" [(ngModel)]="item.Value" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 text-left currency-label">
        <div>
          <select class="form-control form-field field-height" (change)="validateCurrencySelected(item.CurrencyId)" [(ngModel)]="item.CurrencyId" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
          <option *ngFor="let currency of getStoreTypeCurrencies(item.CurrencyId, item.StoreTypeId)">{{currency}}</option>
        </select>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="createStoreType()">+ Add Another Store Type</a>
</div>
</accordion-group>
```

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz sample?

Comment: Did you want to preselect the currency value based on the first row selection? If that's the case you can put the value in a variable then use the same variable for other buttons as well. Then add the disabled function for other rows.